# Need to parse input of a string

Tags: c, string, shell, parsing, filesystems

I am currently in a Systems Software class and we have to implement a UNIX-like shell environment and file system with a hierarchical directory structure. The file system is supposed to be stored in main memory and should allow users to browse the directory structure, create and delete files and directories, etc.

So this is the code I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char cmd[50];
const char spc[50] = " ";
char *file, *dir;
char *tok;

while(1){
    printf("Russ_John_Shell> ");
    fgets(cmd, 50, stdin);
    tok = strtok(cmd, spc);
    if (strcmp(tok, "cd") == 0){
        changeDir(cmd);
    } else if (strcmp(cmd, "ls") == 0){
        listDir(cmd);
    } else if (strcmp(cmd, "mkdir") == 0){
        makeDir(cmd);
    } else if (strcmp(cmd, "mkfs") == 0){
        makeFS(cmd);
    } else if (strcmp(cmd, "rmdir") == 0){
        remDir(cmd);
    } else if (strcmp(cmd, "stat") == 0){
        status(cmd);
    } else if (strcmp(cmd, "mkfile") == 0){
        makeFile(cmd);
    } else if (strcmp(cmd, "rmfile") == 0){
        remFile(cmd);
    } else if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0){
        exitShell(cmd);
    } else {
        printf("Command not recognized.\n");
    }
}
printf("%s","BYE BYE \n");
}
```

When attempting to compile, it says

```
assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
tok = strtok(cmd, spc);
```

and I'm not entirely sure what's wrong.

If i'm not mistaken, I'm supposed to parse the input to read the command at the beginning and then if that command requires a file/directory, parse that part of the string as well. What is wrong with this code and how can I fix this? Any help would do. Thanks.

EDIT: So my problem was that I didn't have `#include <string.h>`. But now, I want the program to know the difference between commands. For example, `ls` doesn't require a file name or directory whereas `mkdir` will need a name of directory. Would an if statement be suffice? If so, how would I go about implementing that?

Comment: Did you `#include <string.h>`?

Comment: Welp... that solves that issue. I could have sworn I had that.

Comment: Ask a new question. Don't keep tacking on more questions. But certainly, it can be implemented with an `if` statement if you so desire. Just give it a go.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will post a new question after I give it a go.